# Pushing Values to Inner Array with Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I need to create a flat array from a nested one.
The input JSON looks like

```json
[
  {
    "resource": "r1",
    "application": "app1",
    "description": "desc1",
    "type": "t1",
    "labels": [
      {
        "instance": "i1",
        "team": "yellow",
        "network": "nnn",
        "environment": "prod",
        "value": 77,
        "stat": "some stat"
      },
      {
        "instance": "i2",
        "team": "green",
        "network": "mmm",
        "environment": "prod",
        "value": 0.1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "resource": "r2",
    "application": "app2",
    "description": "desc2",
    "type": "t2",
    "labels": [
      {
        "instance": "i3",
        "team": "red",
        "network": "vvv",
        "environment": "prod",
        "value": 6457
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The expected output is

```json
[
  {
    "resource": "r1",
    "application": "app1",
    "description": "desc1",
    "type": "t1",
    "instance": "i1",
    "team": "yellow",
    "network": "nnn",
    "environment": "prod",
    "value": 77,
    "stat": "some stat"
  },
  {
    "resource": "r1",
    "application": "app1",
    "description": "desc1",
    "type": "t1",
    "instance": "i2",
    "team": "green",
    "network": "mmm",
    "environment": "prod",
    "value": 0.1
  },
  {
    "resource": "r2",
    "application": "app2",
    "description": "desc2",
    "type": "t2",
    "instance": "i3",
    "team": "red",
    "network": "vvv",
    "environment": "prod",
    "value": 6457
  }
]
```

This is just 1 example, I need to be able to handle data with different keys. Basically every label needs to be an item of the root level array with the keys and values from the resource it is part of added to it. I tried this:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "labels": {
          "*": {
            "*": "[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But the result is

```json
[
  {
    "resource": "r1",
    "application": "app1",
    "description": "desc1",
    "type": "t1",
    "instance": [ "i1" , "i3" ],
    "team": [ "yellow", "red" ],
    "network": [ "nnn", "vvv" ],
    "environment": [ "prod", "prod" ],
    "value": [ 77, 6457 ],
    "stat": "some stat"
  },
  {
    "instance": "i2",
    "team": "green",
    "network": "mmm",
    "environment": "prod",
    "value": 0.1,
    "resource": "r2",
    "application": "app2",
    "description": "desc2",
    "type": "t2"
  }
]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are the outermost keys(`resource`,`application`,`description`,`type`) might be fixed while the elements of the `labels` are brought dynamically ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan That's what i ended up doing for now, but they might not always be fixed.

Comment: I have answer with considering them as fixed if you'd like...

Comment: That would be a great help! Please post it if you can @BarbarosÖzhan :)

Answer (score 0):

By keeping the key-value pairs of outermost elements fixed while keeping them dynamic for the `labels` array, you can use :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "labels": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,resource)": "&3.[&].resource",
            "@(2,application)": "&3.[&].application",
            "@(2,description)": "&3.[&].description",
            "@(2,type)": "&3.[&].type",
            "*": "&3.[&1].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the second spec is used to get rid of the ruins stem from the indexing while seperating the objects.

Comment: I don't know if I should accept this as the solution since this is not exactly what I asked for, but it is very helpful!

Comment: And just a quick note for anyone looking at this, if the output needs to be an array even if there is only one item, change the second spec to "*":"[]".